# Redemption with outlook installed vs stand alone version of MAPI

Tags: outlook, mapi, outlook-redemption

I am trying to know the difference between using

Redemption with outlook installed vs stand alone version of MAPI (without outlook installed) in terms features accessibility, and what you can do with redemption with outlook that you can't do with redemption with MAPI and vice- versa.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of the standalone version of MAPI, chances are there won't be any existing profiles, so RDOSesson.Logoin won't work. RDOSession.LogonExchangeMailbox / LogonHostedExchangeMailbox should still work fine.

Standalone version o MAPI also does not support Unicode PST and MSG files.